# Height of UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been trying to change the height of a pickerView. I would like it to show a single row instead of the default five rows.
help me plz

Comment: It will be insanely hard to scroll at just one row.

Answer (score 5):

Better u can use PickerView Frame like this,

```
    Pickerview.frame = CGRectMake(30,100,170,200);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey somebody gave down vote for me..? If anything means comments reason Pls...?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but you didn't solve the question: "I would like it to show a single row."

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `UIPickerView` can show either 5 rows or 3 rows, depending on the height of the frame you pass to the `-setFrame:` method. When I need a short `UIPickerView`, I'll pass a height of 100. The code in UIKit will adjust that height to be the closest allowed value.

I'll also note that this is for a very good reason. A one row pickerView, as has been noted elsewhere, would be fiendishly difficult to scroll. Also, the number of visible rows must be odd so that the currently selected row will be centered vertically. This means 3 or 5 rows, because 7 would make the thing way too tall to be practical on an iPhone.

As an aside, this also works with `UIDatePicker` for the same reasons. The exception is when the date picker is in the `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`, which does not support the 3-row variant.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely MUST have a one row picker view:

Create a UIView sized 170 wide by 55 tall.

Set the view properties clip subviews = YES

Add a UIPickerView as a subview of the UIView.  Set its origin to 0, -80.5.

Then add a UIImageView sized 170, 55 as a subview to the UIView.  Set its image to the one shown below.

[image: transparent uipickerview frame]

(You can modify the image and make it stretchable to resize it horizontally)

Final Result:

[image: single row picker view]

Answer (score -1):

did you try to implement `numberOfRowsInComponent:` ? If this doesn't change the size, did you try to set the picker's frame ?

ps: I agree with <strike>@Ritheesh</strike>@BoltClock, one row isn't a good idea